# Android Pagination on server or client side

Tags: android, web-services, pagination

I'm developing an android app, which will fetch data from my webservice and display it to user. I have a confusion in deciding where to keep pagination(in client side or server side)

My scenario is, I ll take input from the user and make a call to my webservice, to fetch all the data available for the input(response is in Json format) and then, display the data fetched in **Recyclerview**. I want to display only 50 records initially, then when "show more" button is clicked, the next 50 is displayed.

My data(reponse from webservice) range varies from 0 to 15000 , based on the input from user. And I have other filtering parameters in UI, which will change the rendered data when selected.

So, is it good to fetch all the 15000 records at once and do all kind of processing in client side?

or to fetch 50 records each time when "show more" button is clicked? and to fire new API call whenever filter is changed?

Thanks.

Comment: Do what you want. And try all out. Thats better than asking us whats better.

Comment: i would also suggest pagination but forget the show more or load more button. Just when the user scrolls load the next page. Much more efficient way. Think also for this in the future. Now you have 15000 records, maybe in some time in the future you will have 1.000.000 records. Do it with pagination is my suggestion!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never try to fetch such a large number of records in one go, because : 1) your app would have a very slow FRT (First Response Time) 2) the user is unlikely to view more than a couple hundred records at any given time. 3) If the user data (2G/3G/4G) is paid, the user ends up paying for data that he would never see.

So, you should always have pagination on the server side and then your client can request subsequent records as and when needed.

Having said that, network requests would take time and waiting for response every time user clicks on "Show More" would be bad UX as well. So, you need to consider batching requests together and even pre-fetching some data. Here is a nice video for you to see before changing your architecture : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kOx-IPqtqA